# Revision of Form that does not overwrite original form creates an editable copy

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, infopath-rules, sharepoint-library

I have a InfoPath form 2010, that is being published on SharePoint 2007. Currently once the user submits a form and the form is then reviewed and I have a text box to change it to approved upon this change the fields become read only which I did with conditional formatting.

What is the best way to then allow the user to edit the form and save it as a new item in the library, without the loss/compromise of the original form?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this idea?

> 1) The first thing you need to do is disable the save/save as buttons, and instead of using those on your form, use a custom submit button (no code) by following my blog entry:  [Auto-Generating Filenames for InfoPath Forms](http://claytoncobb.com/2009/06/20/auto-generating-filenames-for-infopath-forms/).
>
> 2) Then, add a 2nd button that does the same thing, but make it so
>   that this either uses a separate submit data connection with a
>   different filename (could just concatenate some text with the now()
>   function on the fly) or that performs some other logic of defining
>   your new filename before submitting with the previous submit data
>   connection
>
> 3) When a form has already been submitted, this new button will show
>   up, and you can name it "Copy Form."  Pushing that button will submit
>   a new XML file to the library with a different name.  Pressing the
>   other button will update the current form.  You can add logic to show
>   or hide either or both buttons depending on the user or status of the
>   form.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2c5e5fb5-62da-4b34-826b-b03927bd7c2a/copy-an-existing-infopath-form?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy

Comment: Let me know if you hit any snags...

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have a submit button currently which saves the file as the title (text field). I want both copies to be saved to the same library but as separate forms. Does adding a second button that submits to the same library cause any problems? For the second submit button is there a way I could do a counter with it to make it unique so if in the submission its called Revision Title 1 or something?

Comment: The 2nd button should not cause issues. You do want to follow his steps for generating unique filenames though. You don't want name conflicts to arise.

You could do something like "Copy of [Form Title]" + now().

Comment: Jpollar it seems now the issue that is occurring is when I open the original and create the copy it works great but after they submit the revised copy it asks them if they want to save the changes to the original which then also updates the original, is there a way that I can stop the box from coming up for that?

Comment: It's trying to save two files with the same name? Or saving two separate files entirely with the same content?

Comment: It works correctly in that it is saving the new file, but its also asking if I want to update the old file. Is there a way I can prevent the pop up?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share the form and empty library template so I can test it on my end?

Comment: At this time I am not able to share the document what is occurring is when I open it the copy is created a pop up upon submission of the copy asks Do you want to shave the changes to (original document)? with a Yes or No option.